# How to explain simple math with correct preposition embedded on explanation?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

I have a construction to say a ratio. I think *of* or *and* would be the correct prepositions.

So, If I give you my practice case

> 1. The ratio *of* minimum rectangle’s floor area *to* enclosed circle area is
>      tested with a defined threshold and a candidate, given a low ratio, is
>      taken as natural object assuming that natural object has a more
>      irregular boundary.
> 2. The ratio *between* floor area of enclosed minimum rectangle *and*
>      enclosed circle area is tested with a defined threshold and a
>      candidate, given a low ratio, is taken as natural object assuming that
>      natural object has a more irregular boundary.

As I cannot figure out the best preposition with the grammatically correct construction, I would like to ask what would be given a grammatically correct sentence?

Comment: As written, this is more like a writing critique, which would be either too localized or off-topic.  If you wanted to reword it as a broader question about the correct preposition to use with "ratio", you might have better results here.

Comment: The ratio of Google hits for "ratio of A to B" to hits for "ratio between A and B" is 6710 : 4230 at my space-time coordinates. (I actually entered the letters.) Substituting X for A and Y for B, the ratio becomes 1240 : 475. Substituting (in the original) B for A and Q for B, the figures are unsurprisingly low, the ratio being 1 : 0 (and virtually meaningless as a statistic). Both are permitted, but we wouldn't usually say _the ratio between P and Q is 7 : 5_ (ie we usually use of / to if we're giving the **value** of the ratio).

Comment: I think you need more work on articles (a, an, the) than on *of* or *between*.

Comment: @GEdgar: yes. i am not native english speaker... could you please show me my errors in the sentence

Comment: *And* is not a preposition. It's a conjunction.

Comment: I have a construction to say a ratio. I think of or and would be the correct prepositions.

So, If I give you my practice case ->

I need to know the usual English construction/s used when talking about ratios. 

Here are the two ways I think may be correct:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently studying a Phd in mathematics.  I would write:

> The ratio between the floor areas of an enclosed minimum rectangle and an enclosed circle is tested with a defined threshold. A candidate, given a low ratio, ...

Answer (score 4):

Either combination is fine. If it helps any, in mathematics, when the colon is used to denote a ratio, it is customarily *read* as *to* or *is to*. From [Wikipedia's colon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29#Mathematics_and_logic):

> The colon is used in mathematics, cartography, model building and other fields to denote a ratio or a scale, as in 3:1 (pronounced “**three to one**”). When a ratio is reduced to a simpler form, such as 10:15 to 2:3, this may be expressed with a double colon as 10:15::2:3; this would be read "**10 is to 15 as 2 is to 3**". Unicode provides a distinct character U+2236 ∶ ratio for mathematical usage.